# Holiday logic to include in the Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working for a payroll system for my client and they have multiple business rules.

There are weekday, weekend, and holiday rules applicable. Day shift starts at 06:00 and ends at 22:59 for a given date. Night shift starts from 23:00 of present date and ends at 05:59 of next day morning.

I'm getting list of Holidays in an array and I'm searching the dates have any match with the employee working date.

Say a employee starts working at 25-Dec(X-Max) 22:00 on Friday and ends his work on 22:50 same day. Again he starts working on 26-Dec (Holiday) 01:00 in Saturday and completes his work on 02:45 same day.

For this given example,

employee works 00:59 hours in Holiday - Day shift which is from 22:00 to 22:50
Employee works 1:45 hours in Holiday(previous day shift timings 25-Dec X-Max) - Night shift which is from 01:00 to 2:45

I'm working on VBA code to find logic for this.

My code works perfectly fine for all the weekday and weekend shift timing logic except holidays:

```
Sub Test()

    PayRoleTime "11/27/2020  10:00:00 PM", "11/28/2020 10:00:00 AM"

End Sub

Public Function PayRoleTime(startTime As Date, endTime As Date)
'Declare Variables
    Dim startDbl, startHour, startMin, startHourMin As Double
    Dim endDbl, endHour, endMin, endHourMin As Double
    Dim currentDbl, currentHour, currentMin, currentHourMin As Double
    Dim workWeekDay(1) As Double
    Dim nightShift(1) As Double
    Dim startingDay As Double
    Dim output As Variant
    Dim currentWeekday As Integer
    
'Set Variables for Company Shift Structure
    workWeekDay(0) = 2
    workWeekDay(1) = 6
    nightShift(0) = 23
    nightShift(1) = 6
    ReDim output(5)

'Set Variables from Inputs
    startDbl = CDbl(startTime) + 0.00000033
    startingDay = Int(startDbl)
    startDay = weekDay(startingDay)
    startHour = (startDbl - Int(startDbl)) * 24
    startMin = Int((startHour - Int(startHour)) * 60)
    startHour = Int((startDbl - Int(startDbl)) * 24)
    startHourMin = startHour + (startMin / 100)
    
    endDbl = CDbl(endTime) + 0.00000033
    endingDay = Int(endDbl)
    endDay = weekDay(endingDay)
    endHour = (endDbl - Int(endDbl)) * 24
    endMin = Int((endHour - Int(endHour)) * 60)
    endHour = Int((endDbl - Int(endDbl)) * 24)
    endHourMin = endHour + (endMin / 100)
    
    currentDbl = startingDay
    currentHour = startHour
    currentMin = startMin
    currentHourMin = startHourMin
'Loop to get working hour times
    Do While (currentDbl < endingDay Or currentHour < endHour Or currentMin < endMin)
            currentWeekday = weekDay(currentDbl)
            currentHourMin = currentHour + (currentMin / 100)
            
        If currentWeekday >= workWeekDay(0) And currentWeekday <= workWeekDay(1) Then
            If currentHourMin >= nightShift(0) Or currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                If currentWeekday = workWeekDay(0) And currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                    output(5) = output(5) + 1 'Increment Sunday Night Shift
                Else
                    output(1) = output(1) + 1 'Increment Weekday Night Shift
                End If
            Else
                output(0) = output(0) + 1 'Increment Weekday Day Shift
            End If
        ElseIf currentWeekday < workWeekDay(0) Then
            If currentHourMin >= nightShift(0) Or currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                If currentWeekday < workWeekDay(0) And currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                    output(3) = output(3) + 1 'Increment Saturday Night Shift
                Else
                    output(5) = output(5) + 1 'Increment Sunday Night Shift
                End If
            Else
                output(4) = output(4) + 1 'Increment Sunday Day Shift
            End If
        ElseIf currentWeekday > workWeekDay(1) Then
            If currentHourMin > nightShift(0) Or currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                If currentWeekday > workWeekDay(1) And currentHourMin < nightShift(1) Then
                    output(1) = output(1) + 1 'Increment Weekday Night Shift
                Else
                    output(3) = output(3) + 1 'Increment Saturday Night Shift
                End If
            Else
                output(2) = output(2) + 1 'Increment Saturday Day Shift
            End If
        End If

        'Increment Time
            currentMin = currentMin + 1
            If currentMin = 60 Then
                currentMin = 0
                currentHour = currentHour + 1
            End If
            If currentHour = 24 Then
                currentHour = 0
                currentDbl = currentDbl + 1
            End If

    Loop
    
   
    
'Print Results to Immediate Window
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(0) / 60 & " Hours, Weekday Day Shift"
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(1) / 60 & " Hours, Weekday Night Shift"
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(2) / 60 & " Hours, Saturday Day Shift"
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(3) / 60 & " Hours, Saturday Night Shift"
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(4) / 60 & " Hours, Sunday Day Shift"
    Debug.Print "Employee worked " & output(5) / 60 & " Hours, Sunday Night Shift"
End Function
```

Comment: What's the problem? What means "it's not working"

Comment: `Dim endDbl, endHour, endMin, endHourMin As Double` declares 3 `Variants` but only 1 `Double`. Unfortunately, VBA requires that the type of each non-variant variable be explicitly declared. You would need `Dim endDbl As Double, endHour As Double, endMin As Double, endHourMin As Double` to declare all 4 to be doubles.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz In my Payroll Holiday list, I have 25 to 31 as holidays and some of the date in weekday's as holidays. I want all these to be marked as Sunday timings to incorporate with the above code. I have made changes to identify the given date as holiday. But when two holidays come together, at mid night from 00:00 to 5:59 it is marking as Saturday instead of holiday

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank for letting me know i'll correct that

Comment: @ArunSinghG what you mention is another problem different than the stated in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Excel Worksheet Function `WORKDAY` to determine if the day is a holiday. You must supply a list of dates that are holidays to this function. Use an array that holds all the holiday dates as the second parameter to WorkDay.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDay, arrHolidays)
```

SOURCE: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33

Comment: “ Excel comes with built-in list of Holidays that comes from Windows”. That’s news to me: how can I access that list?

Comment: @DS_London, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: @HackSlash I know there is a function for finding the Holidays. But this is not serving my purpose. If you read the description, my work day is starting from 6:00 to next day 5:59. But this function will work as 00:00 to 23:59 as a single work day.

Comment: What is your requirement?